# Numpy: Find the value needed in one equation which minimizes the error

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, equation-solving, scipy-optimize-minimize

the title is not clear, i hope to explain better here:

i have the two following arrays, `ep` and `sp` with the same dimension:

```
ep = [0.00000000e+00, 4.29973987e-05, 1.77977219e-04, 3.08940223e-04, 4.44883670e-04, 5.84806153e-04, 7.28705999e-04, 8.77580573e-04, 1.03342551e-03, 1.19623754e-03, 1.36301748e-03, 1.53675860e-03, 1.72145026e-03. 1.91608833e-03]

sp = [336.17311024, 366.02001118, 427.4927458,  471.53403676, 503.53359236, 527.23879184, 544.98822976, 558.34153011, 568.29913137, 575.9109472, 581.00400657, 584.97104685, 587.14272582, 587.92832846]
```

I need to obtain an array `sw` as per the following formula:

```
sw = (np.amax(sp)/(ei**(ei+c))) * ((ep+ei)**(ei+c))
```

where `c` is the max value of `ep` array and `ei` has to be the value that minimize the sum of the following other equation (after the iteration for each value of sp and sw):

```
f = (sp - sw)**2
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Try building insight for the problem by plotting `f` as a function of a range of `ei` values.  That may help you determine how difficult the optimization challenge will be, and will also give you some hints about its optimal value.

Comment: after that check out the `scipy` `optimize` module, which provides a number of algorithms to find the best `ei`.

Comment: also watch out for the `^` operator.  In matlab it means "raise to the power" but in python it means "exclusive or".  use `**` or `numpy.power()` instead

Comment: @AbbeGijly yes, i konw about the ^ symbol. I replaced it with ** in the question in order to avoid confiusion for other readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? You have already described your error function so can use `scipy.optimize.minimize` to minimize it:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ep = np.array([0.0000000e+00, 4.29973987e-05, 1.77977219e-04, 3.08940223e-04, 4.44883670e-04, 5.84806153e-04, 7.28705999e-04, 8.77580573e-04, 1.03342551e-03, 1.19623754e-03, 1.36301748e-03, 1.53675860e-03, 1.72145026e-03, 1.91608833e-03])

sp = np.array([336.17311024, 366.02001118, 427.4927458, 471.53403676, 503.53359236, 527.23879184, 544.98822976, 558.34153011, 568.29913137, 575.9109472, 581.00400657, 584.97104685, 587.14272582, 587.92832846])

def err(ei, c):
    sw = (sp/ei**(ei+c))*((ep+ei)**(ei+c))

    return np.sum((sp-sw)**2)

# do minimization
c = max(ep)
guess = [1.2]
res = minimize(err, guess, args=(c,), method='Nelder-Mead')
# get miniization result
ei, = res.x

# plot results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax[0].plot(sp)
ax[0].plot((sp/ei**(ei+c))*((ep+ei)**(ei+c)))
ax[0].set_title('Function evaluation')

ax[1].plot((sp/ei**(ei+c))*((ep+ei)**(ei+c)) - sp, label='Minimized')
ei, = guess
ax[1].plot((sp/ei**(ei+c))*((ep+ei)**(ei+c)) - sp, label='Initial Guess')
ax[1].set_title('Difference')
ax[1].legend()
```

[image: minimized fn]

Comment: Ok thanks, seems good. I'll try some set of data and compare them to the optimization done previously by excel solver. Do you suggest the Nelder-Mead method of optimization in particular or are there any other methods that you can suggest? Thanks again.

Comment: Problem: c is a constant number, the max of ep array, and it has  to remain that value. If i try to delete it from the arg and res i have these errors related to the line of the sw calculation: 1)RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power - 2)RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply

Comment: I see. You can add constants to the minimisation function as extra arguments, and pass them through `args` of the `minimize` function. I have edited the above to acommodate for this. The difference is that the first argument of your minimisation function are the parameters that are minimised, so by adding `c` as a separate argument we can keep it constant. Just a note, the minimisation of `ei=143.0` in this case, but the overall minimisation isn't as good as when minimising with `c` as well. The total sum of differences is smaller in the minimised case.

Comment: My mistake, i found the cause of the error: the formula was wrong. It wasn't correct to put sp (array) in the sw calculation, I had to replace it with the max value of sp. Doing so it works perfectly without warnings. Thanks again.